# Adding tracelistener to web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, logging, tracelistener

I want to use below code with a website. Which `config sections` I should add to `web.config` to log the output into a file or windows eventlog ?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// Singleton in real code
Class Logger
{
   // In constructor: Trace.AutoFlush = false;

   public void Log(message)
   {
       String formattedLog = formatLog(message);
       Trace.TraceInformation(formattedLog);
       Trace.Flush();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use `system.diagnostics` section.
Here's example from MSDN for text file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" 
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
          initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

This is for system events log: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener.aspx

Comment: Logging to windows event-log is not straight forward with asp.net since it requires administrative privileges.

Comment: do you think any changes in the web.config _listiners_ section is required to allow logging into EventLog ?

Comment: do you just need this code on the web config or do you also need the following code?     ' Create a trace listener for the event log.
    Dim myTraceListener As New EventLogTraceListener("myEventLogSource")

    ' Add the event log trace listener to the collection.
    Trace.Listeners.Add(myTraceListener)

    ' Write output to the event log.
    Trace.WriteLine("Test output")

Comment: where will the TextWriterOutput.log file be outputted to?

Comment: file will be outputted in the place (folder) where process started. You can also specify full path there.

Comment: I still got no log file output until I turned off custom errors.  <system.web><customErrors mode="Off"/> ...

Comment: I would suggest using something like Log4Net.  It will give you better control over your logging.  Also WARNING: note that the TextWriterTraceListener does not have a max file size!  Right now I am looking into a customer complaint that someone left this running and they now have a massive log file!  It will just keep going until it fills the drive.