# How to write to output in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to debug my asp.net application and have been stuck on this for too long.  I want to output a simple "TEST" for testing.

I have tried:

```
Console.WriteLine("TEST");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TEST");
Console.Write("TEST");
```

I am looking in the output window.  What am I missing?

Comment: You are writing to the console. Are you looking at the Output window below project explorer? Also, since it's a web app, I would prefer to test to see if I can get output onto a web browser.

Comment: Are you in debug mode? Otherwise the second line won't output anything. The others are due to not being a console app.

Comment: If you're working with a Web application, there is no need to write to a console window.

Answer (score 2):

You're running this code in a web app, which doesn't have a console. Use `Trace.WriteLine`, and configure it correctly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004494/8446), for example.